# Unsure about my compilation errors: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c

When I try submitting my code to my prof, I get a compilation error with the following message:

> `ipc_ms1.c: In function ‘getDbl’:
>    ipc_ms1.c:146:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>    ipc_ms1.c: In function ‘getInt’:
>    ipc_ms1.c:122:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

I'm not sure what to do

```
#include <stdio.h>

void welcome(void);
int getInt(void);
double getDbl(void);
void prnTitle(void);
void prnFooter(double gTotal);
void pause(void);
double getDblLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit);

void welcome(void)
{
printf("---=== Grocery Inventory System ===---\n");

}

void prnTitle(void)
{
printf("Row |SKU| Name \t | Price |Taxed| Qty | Min |  Total  |Atn \n");
printf("----+---+--------------------+--------+-----+-----+-----+------------+|---\n");

}
void prnFooter(double gTotal)
{
printf("--------------------------------------------------------+-----------  ------\n");
//float  gTotal = 1234.57;
while (gTotal > 0)
{
    printf("%12.21f", gTotal);
}
}
void clrKyb(void)
{
char b;
while (b != '\n')
{
    scanf("%c", &b);
}

}
 void pause(void)
{
printf("Press <Enter> to continue...");

clrKyb();

}
int getInt(void)
{
printf("Enter an interger:");
int d;
char c;
scanf("%d%c", &d, &c);
while (c != '\n')
{
    printf("Invalid integer, please try again ");
    scanf("%d%c", &d, &c);
}
}
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
int a;
printf("Enter an integer between %d and %d:", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
scanf("%d", &a);
while (a <= lowerLimit || a >= upperLimit)
{
    printf("Invalid value, %d < value < %d:", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    scanf("%d", &a);
}
return a;
}
double getDbl(void)
{
double d;
char c;
printf("Enter a floating point number:");
scanf("%lf,%c", &d, &c);
while (c != '\n')
{
    printf("Invalid number, please try again ");
    scanf("%lf%c", &d, &c);
}

}

double getDblLimited(double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
{
double a;
printf("Enter a floating point number between %f and %f:", lowerLimit,   upperLimit);
scanf("%lf", &a);
while (a <= lowerLimit || a >= upperLimit)
{
    printf("Invalid value, %f < value < %f:", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
    scanf("%lf", &a);
}
return a;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: where's `main` function ??

Comment: this is a 6 part project and for this part of the submission we were told to not include the main function

Comment: Please (doc-)comment and format your source code properly. Don't write and _never present uncommented code_. Ponder why it doesn't complain about `int getInt(void)` (or does it? How about `double getDblLimited()`?). (Those repeated `scanf()`-calls per `getType()` should be avoided.)

Comment: indent your code properly

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `return` anything from `getDbl`.

Comment: how would I return it

Comment: Your code already demonstrates how to return values from a function. I don't know the requirements of your code (specifically why you're scanning two values) so I can't tell you what to write. This is your code.

Comment: At the end of getDbl() add:  return(d);   You have a similar problem with getInt().

Comment: What exactly does that do?

Comment: You need to read a book on C or ask your instructor. Stack overflow does not exist to teach programming fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

These are only warnings; says that function `getDbl` reaches the end of its implementation without returning anything. But it shows you don't realy know what you're doing. Follow Jonathan advice and [find a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

I'll explain the warning:

Since it declared `double <function_name>(<param_list>)` it means you have a `return` statement to add at the end:

## `getDbl`

```
double getDbl(void) {
  double d;
  char c;
  printf("Enter a floating point number:");
  scanf("%lf,%c", &d, &c);
  while (c != '\n') {
    printf("Invalid number, please try again ");
    scanf("%lf%c", &d, &c);
  }
  return d;
}
```

## `getInt`

```
int getInt(void) {
  printf("Enter an interger:");
  int d;
  char c;
  scanf("%d%c", &d, &c);
  while (c != '\n') {
    printf("Invalid integer, please try again ");
    scanf("%d%c", &d, &c);
  }
  return d;
}
```

(and see how to [format your code properly](http://www.icsharpcode.net/TechNotes/SharpDevelopCodingStyle03.pdf))